# predict car position after making a circular movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, geometry, 2d

I have a car in position **p** of a 2D world. The car look vector is a normalized vector **d**.

The radius of the circle is **r = 2/π**.

I want to create a function `predict(p, d, clockwise, angle)` that, given the initial position `p`, the look direction `d`, it returns the final position of the car after turning `angle` degrees. If it is clockwise, it rotates in the circle `R`, otherwise it rotates in `L`.

[image: [1]]

Example: if I call `predict( (0,0), (0,1), true, 90 )`, that means the car is in (0,0), looking up and it should rotate 90º clockwise, stopping in position (2/π, 2/π).

I tried to do everything supposing the car always looks up and then rotate the results according with its true angle but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to find the center of the circle, then rotate `p` around the center. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
d' = Rotate(d, clockwise ? -90 : 90)
circle_center = p + d' * circle_radius // Here, circle_radius is 2/pi
relative_p = p - circle_center
rotated_p = circle_center + Rotate(relative_p, clockwise ? -angle : angle)
```

This method will work for any `p`, `d`, and `circle_radius`.

Comment: I think there's something missing in the logic, it is wrong when I test but not totally wrong, it always get one coordinate right and other wrong.

Comment: @Daniel You're right, there was a mistake. I fixed it. The `rotated_p` vector should have been offset using `circle_center` instead of `p`. And this makes the optimization not useful anymore.

Comment: Good, @Gilles-Philippe Paillé, now it is working perfectly.

Comment: @Daniel Great! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Gilles-Philippe Paillé idea of rotating around a point and defined a method for this task:

```
Vector2 RotateAround(Vector2 v, Vector2 pivot, float angle) { //angle in degrees
    angle *= Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    float x = Mathf.Cos(angle) * (v.x - pivot.x) - Mathf.Sin(angle) * (v.y - pivot.y) + pivot.x;
    float x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * (v.x - pivot.x) + Mathf.Cos(angle) * (v.y - pivot.y) + pivot.y;
    return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```

Then, to predict the final position, given `position`, `lookDirection`, `angle` and `clockwise`:

```
Vector2 PredictPosition(Vector2 position, Vector2 lookDirection, float angle, bool clockwise){
    float radius = 2f / Mathf.PI;
    Vector2 pivot = position + radius * (clockwise ? RIGHT : LEFT);
    return RotateAround(transform.position, pivot, clockwise ? -angle : angle);
}
```

Where `RIGHT` and `LEFT` are the vectors corresponding to the car looking right and left (that is just `lookDirection` rotated 90º and -90º. Using `RotateAround(lookDirection, Vector2.zero, 90)` you get one of them, the latter is just the negation of the former.